# Recommendations for translating an app in arabic

Tags: php, html, arabic, right-to-left

For an upcoming project, one of the requirements is to translate the web application in a few languages, one of which is in Arabic.

I know plenty about dealing with multiple languages, and know plenty about unicode. What I'm wondering is if there's some basic tips and recommendations I can follow anticipating an Arabic translation for my HTML templates.

Edit: I'm mostly curious how to build an application that's easily translatable. With all LTR-languages it's often times a matter of string replacement (along with a few other things), what does it take to build an app, but make it relativaly easy to add arabic support later on. Are there things I can consider before starting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the HTML `dir` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I underestimated the usefulness of dir.. Just that will get me a long way, thanks so much!

Comment: I've noticed dir only deals with table order and text alignment (mostly). How about interface design, any tips there?

Comment: @Evert, unfortunately I don't really have any UI tips. I'm a developer at Formstack, our Arabic support for our forms simply use the dir attribute and we haven't had any complaints... I'm sure other improvements do exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can start from the dir attribute. But it's not enough if you want a complete mirrored interface, because "dir" only deals with the text-direction.

What you need is a clean semantic markup in your HTML template with the styles separated in CSS stylesheets, so you can easily link your HTML template to an LTR or RTL style sheet according to the current langauge.

Check this [tutorial](http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/rtling-hello-world-webpage) and this [one](http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/3-different-ways-rtl-your-css)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of overseeing Arabic translation localization projects, you might want to consider two major options:

1) Make the app really internationalized
2) Make a separate one just for Arabic

I imagine you'd probably like to avoid the second option. When it comes to making the app as international as possible, you really need to think from a cultural perspective. I'll try and give as many details as I can:

**Iconography**
You already know you need to flip lots of icons for RTL languages, but don't overlook the fact the icons might not be that international anyway e.g. using the post office icon for mail

**Numbers and dates**
There's actually different numbers and ways of writing dates in Arabic. Instead of hardcoding this, get it to use the system's numbers/dates.

**Culture and Colours**
I don't know what your app does, but check out how appropriate images and colour are before you start. For example, if your logo is a dog, that isn't going to go down well in Arabic cultures, where dogs are seen as evil animals. Green is often seen as an erudite colour in the west or representing nature, but in Arabic cultures it's the colour of peace and harmony.

**Parsing strings**
When you come to building your strings, it's very easy to think one sentence one string. That's not the case. Break the sentence down into the smallest parts you possibly can. For example:

There's a blue house on the hill --> There's | a blue house | on the hill

"a blue house" is better together than three separate strings because in languages like Arabic the word 'blue' and even 'a' can change form depending on the grammatical structure of the sentence.

**Commenting** When you're preparing your strings for translation, make use of comments for the translator. You don't need to comment everything but it's useful to give context to things that might be immediately obvious e.g. "Print" does this mean the action 'to print' or is it a physical print?